# Firefox dev tools + Chrome debugger consoles buggy display of javascript object references

Tags: javascript, reference, firebug, firefox-developer-tools

I'm experiencing some unusual behavior in Firefox Dev Tools. After filtering some elements out of an object with lodash, the console is displaying a reference to the previous unfiltered version of the object, but only on the right side pane.

[image: debug bug]

On the left, it shows 2 elements, which is the result I expected. On the right it shows the original unfiltered 17 elements. I've actually experienced this before on rare occasions with Firebug before I was forced to switch to Dev Tools with the recent discontinuation of FB.

If nobody else has experienced this, I could attempt to distill it to a minimal case example, but I'd prefer to just work around it, if it's a known bug.

Leaning toward believing my object is actually filtered as indicated on the left but this is a bit unnerving.

Updates:

Using Firefox 51 Linux

Chrome is actually doing the same thing. It shows `array[2]` with 17 elements:

[image: chrome debugger]

Comment: Are you sure you're logging the filtered version in both places? `filter` won't mutate your array, so the unfiltered array still exists.

Comment: hard to help without a working example. Objects in console do have inheritance and aren't snapshots. Try JSON.stringify version and compare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you inspect an array its *current* value is displayed, i.e. the value at the time you click the logged variable. This value may differ to the one logged to the console.

The Chrome DevTools show a little [image: Info icon shown besides an expanded array variable] icon besides the array explaining this on hover.

[image: Chrome DevTools showing expanded array variable and tooltip explaining why the item count differs]

This means, at the time the variable is logged it indeed had only two items in it, but at the time you clicked it, it was obviously unfiltered again.

Comment: Thanks.  They should change console.log() to console.confuse()  Last I checked, the purpose of a log was to record events as they happen in sequence... shrug :-/

Comment: It's obviously a compromise they made in regard of performance, because if they kept every logged object in memory, memory comsumption would go up very fast. As @charlietfl mentioned, using `JSON.stringify()` is an easy workaround for this.